# Including square brackets in variable values

Tags: bash, variable

In the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar
set -e

fwd_slsh='/'
space=' '
ampersands='&&'
bang='!'
opnbrc='['
clsbrc=']'
caret='^'

prefix=${bang}${fwd_slsh}${opnbrc}${caret}
suffix=${clsbrc}${fwd_slsh}

echo $prefix
echo $suffix
```

the resultant output is as shown below:

```
!/^
/
```

The resulting echo output omits the '[' and the ']'.

What is the change required to the above script so that both '[' and ']' are included in the echo outputs? Just wanted to reiterate that I would want to retain the above convention if possible, that is, include both the '[' and ']' as part of the variables as shown above.

My intention is to use the variables `prefix` and `suffix` in awk commands, along with other variables input by the user during runtime.

Appreciate your thoughts.

TIA

Vinod

Comment: Odd, works as required for me. What version of bash?

Comment: I get GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) when I run bash --version

Comment: oh, maybe something changed in bash between that and 5.1.4 - have you tried `prefix="${bang}${fwd_slsh}${opnbrc}${caret}"` - i.e. add quotes?

Comment: try `opnbrc='\['`

Comment: I can't reproduce with the exact same version. Try running `bash -x ./that-script` which might give you a clue. In any case you forgot the quotes around the expansions in `echo $prefix` and `echo $suffix` and remember `echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data. More on that at [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694) and [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803)

Comment: How exactly are you executing the code that you show?

Comment: I have tried all the suggestions but none of them seem to work, including printf. I am just not able to see the '[' or ']' in the output.